# Why does my switch statement print a case and default?

Tags: c, switch-statement, do-while

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char ch;
    int end=0;
    printf("\nPick a letter a through f. (f ends the program)");
    do
    {
        scanf("%c", &ch);

        switch (ch) {
    case 'a':
        printf("a. another: ");
        break;
    case 'b':
        printf("b. another: ");
        break;
    case 'c':
        printf("c: another ");
        break;
    case 'd':
        printf("d. another: ");
        break;
    case 'e':
        printf("e. another:  ");
        break;
    case 'f':
        printf("f. Goodbye. ");
        end=1;
        break;
    default:
        printf("That wasn't a through f. ");
        break;
        }
    } while (end == 0);
    return 0;
}
```

So if you enter a then it will say:

```
a. another: That wasn't a through f.
```

If you enter say g then it will say:

```
That wasn't a through f. That wasn't a through f.
```

If you enter f then it will do as expected

```
f. Goodbye.
```

and the program terminates.

Any tips on how to fix this? I've tried looking it up for a while and I get answers not in C or they say you're forgetting a break; statement. I'm new to C, as well so maybe it's something obvious I'm not noticing, I also thought it might be due to something with the do while loop? Thanks for your time

Comment: Problem is with `scanf("%c", &ch);` Fix by adding a space in it: `scanf(" %c", &ch);`

Comment: scanf with no whitespace in the format specifier will not treat whitespace any differently to any other character.  It's executing the loop once for the `a` and then again for the newline

Comment: Thank you for the explanation on scanf. I had no idea it worked like that. case '\n': break; and scanf(" %c", &ch); both work equally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scanf("%c", &ch)` reads one character at a time. If you're typing a letter and then hitting Enter, then you're providing two characters: the letter, and a newline character (U+000A, `'\n'`).

If you want to ignore newline characters, one option is to explicitly check for them:

```
case '\n':
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using this method..

`scanf("%c\n", &ch);`

It will automatically eat the excess \n characters